# What is the difference between CPython 27m and 27mu?

Tags: python, cpython, python-wheel, python-manylinux

I'm trying to build a python wheel of a project and for that purpose I have to use manylinux (the project contain C & Fortran code).

When I use manylinux to generate wheels, I get 6 files :

- cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
- cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
- cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
- cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
- cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
- cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

I understand that there is a file for each python version but can someone explain me why is there two files for python 2.7 (cp27m & cp27mu) ?

Comment: The README file in https://github.com/pypa/manylinux addresses the differences.
It has to do with the two ABI-incompatible ways of building CPython: `--enable-unicode=ucs2` and `--enable-unicode=ucs4`.